# Which of these is the better (efficient/clean) way of setting up a repeating timed task in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, timer

While searching for a way to set up a repeating timed function in Angular, I came across a myriad of different implementations. I would like to know which one of them would be the better way to do it.

Implementations I've come across:

***setInterval***

```
this.interval = setInterval( () => { 
    // doSomething();
}, 1000);
```

---

***Observable.interval***

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'; // Angular 6

  Observable.interval(2000 * 60).subscribe(
    x => {
      // doSomething();
  });
```

---

***Observable.timer***

```
let timer = Observable.timer(2000,1000);
timer.subscribe(
  t => {
    // doSomething();
});
```

---

***IntervalObservable***

```
IntervalObservable.create(1000).subscribe(
  x => {
    // doSomething();
});
```

---

***TimerObservable***

```
TimerObservable.create(0, this.interval)
  .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
  .subscribe(() => {
      this.myExampleService.get()
      .subscribe((data) => {
          this.data = data;
          if(!this.display){
            this.display = true;
          }
      });
  });
```

---

***rxjs timer***

```
import { timer, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, takeUntil, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

private fetchData$: Observable<string> = this.myservice.checkdata();
private refreshInterval$: Observable<string> = timer(0, 1000)
.pipe(
  // This kills the request if the user closes the component 
  takeUntil(this.killTrigger),
  // switchMap cancels the last request, if no response have been received since last tick
  switchMap(() => this.fetchData$),
  // catchError handles http throws 
  catchError(error => of('Error'))
);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Posting here as I'm nowhere near an expert on the subject: `setInterval` is the basic JS way (no RxJS). `Observable.interval`, `IntervalObservable.create` and (rxjs) `interval` are three ways of doing the RxJS equivalent to `setInterval`. `Observable.timer`, (rxjs) `timer` and `TimerObservable.create` (also all equivalent to each other) take an additional parameter for the first emitted value. In both cases, not entirely sure which way is more modern; with RxJS 6, I believe the ones imported from `rxjs` are.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I know what to use a little better now.